# Unexpected end of JSON input - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy haciendo un bot de Discord con Discord.js, el punto es que estoy haciendo un comando que reproduzca una canción de YouTube colocando el nombre de la canción y reproduzca el primer resultado. El problema es que al intentar sacar la ID del vídeo del archivo "search.json" me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: F:\Bot\json\search.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Aquí hay una parte del código. Agradecería demasiado si lograran ayudarme. (;

```
var videoSearch = args.slice(0).join(' ');
         youtube.search.list({
            part: 'snippet',
            q: videoSearch
            }, function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                 console.error('Error: ' + err);
              }
              if (data) {
                 console.log(data.config.url);
                 var jsonSearch = fs.createWriteStream('./json/search.json', "utf-8");
                 var request = https.get(data.config.url, function(response) {
                    response.pipe(jsonSearch);
                 });
                 let vidId = require('../../json/search.json');
                 console.log(`\n${vidId.items[0].id.videoId}\n`);
```

EDIT: Así queda el archivo "search.json" si se coloca "mercury" por ejemplo:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"j6xRRd8dTPVVptg711_CSPADRfg/BuzsAU-m_62qbjZxWe6680bPe38\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "CO",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"j6xRRd8dTPVVptg711_CSPADRfg/vX41eMGILhhOwRj1Lg_UWz-OuBY\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "31j4DIpgY9U"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-09-08T09:50:10.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCkQ62tvPlVVb2WLppjRfPdQ",
    "title": "GHOSTEMANE - Mercury",
    "description": "CHECK OUT OUR STORE https://trash.clothing TRASH Official Spotify Playlist: ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/31j4DIpgY9U/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/31j4DIpgY9U/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/31j4DIpgY9U/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "ＴＲＡＳＨ 新 ドラゴン",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"j6xRRd8dTPVVptg711_CSPADRfg/5Wnqe81_9i8hfOrQRztIQTyXCcA\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "V2t0FU1XeDE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-10-30T12:00:01.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCnWT-K6shcsSkfJGkpYZC1w",
    "title": "GHOSTEMANE - Mercury [Lyrics / Lyric Video]",
    "description": "You are listening to: GHOSTEMANE - Mercury   Support the Artist(s) below: GHOSTEMANE   ○https://soundcloud.com/ghostemane ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V2t0FU1XeDE/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V2t0FU1XeDE/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/V2t0FU1XeDE/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "RapLayer",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Estoy intentando sacar el "videoId" para colocar el enlace tipo `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`

Comment: ¿Cómo está quedando tu search.json?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta añadiendo el código de search.json (:

Comment: Tienes un problema de asincronía. Mete las siguientes 2 líneas dentro de tu `callback` (justo después de la llamada a `response.pipe`): `let vidId = require('../../json/search.json');` y `console.log(\`\n${vidId.items[0].id.videoId}\n\`);`. Comenta el resultado. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

¡Logré solucionarlo! Intente colocando las líneas `let vidId = require('../../json/search.json');` y `` console.log(`\n${vidId.items[0].id.videoId}\n`); `` pero me seguía dando el error `Unexpected end of JSON input`, así que decidí colocarlas dentro de la función que añade al bot al canal de voz:

```
if (!msg.guild.voiceConnection) {
   msg.member.voiceChannel.join()
      .then(function(connection) {
         let search = require('../../json/search.json');
         console.log(`\n${search.items[0].id.videoId}\n`);
         args[0] = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${search.items[0].id.videoId}`;
         console.log(`\n${search.items[0].snippet.title}\n`);
         server.queue.push(args[0]);
         play(connection, msg);
         msg.delete();
         const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor('#11FF00')
            .setTitle(`Reproduciendo **${search.items[0].snippet.title}**... `)
            .setTimestamp();
         const nEmbed = new RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(bot.user.username, bot.user.displayAvatarURL)
            .setColor('#11FF00')
            .setTitle('¡Listo! ')
            .setTimestamp();
         msg.channel.send(embed)
            .then(m => setTimeout(function () {
               m.edit(nEmbed)
               m.delete(3000)
            }, 3000));
      });
}
```

Y ahora sí obtiene la ID del vídeo buscado y la reproduce sin problema. Gracias a Mauricio Contreras que me dio la noción y espero que le sirva a quien quiera hacer un bot de música. ¡Gracias!